# git with ssh error: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: windows-7, ssh, permissions, git

I'm trying to build a git repo server with a windows remote. Here is my ssh server and local client building environment:

**Server env**
1. windows os
2. mysysgit installed
3. copssh installed
4. remote cloud server

**client**
1. centOS 7 on vmware
2. local pc

Here is my already taken actions.

1. generate a public-private key pair with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on my centos client
2. add a git user named **svccopssh** in my remote windows server
3. copy my centos `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the server folder `d:/Users/svccopssh/.ssh`, in which copssh reads public-ssh-key, and rename it as `authorized_keys`
4. run test:
`ssh -vT svccopssh@remoteIP`

The result comes out like this:

```
[is_january@localhost .ssh]$ ssh -vT svccopssh@120.76.123.231
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 120.76.123.231 [120.76.123.231] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDS 26:95:35:2c:32:ad:46:14:94:5e:71:95:b7:f7:2d:aa
debug1: Host '120.76.123.231' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/is_january/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/is_january/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/is_january/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/is_january/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Any suggestions ? I am sure that the same public-key works well on github ssh-key

Comment: What about `ssh -vvvT svccopssh@remoteIP`? More `-v` = more verbose. Also try to check the server logs. You might see a problem with the `authorized_keys` file (permission problem or similar).

Comment: @GuillaumeBoudreau That's right. It's the wrong location of authorized_key which results in the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, I've figured out what the problem is and solved it after all.

When I installed my copssh client, there was a step which asked me to choose user directory. I used my customized configuration, which was directory `d:/Users/svccopssh/.ssh`. However, the exact directory where svccopssh reads public-keys from is `d:/copssh/home/svccopssh/.ssh`, obviously not the directory I've used in my installation. After I changed my authorized_keys location to the right place: `path/to/copssh_loaction/home/yourUserName/.ssh`, it worked.